# Hello. I do not understand these questions. Please explain them to me

Tags: american-english

[image]

I do not understand these questions. Please explain them to me.

Comment: Welcome to ELL. You may want to take the [tour] to learn more about how this site works - it's a bit different from other sites. Do not post pictures of text. Transcribe the text that you are asking about, so that other learners can search for and find it, and so that people who use screen readers can understand your question. You should only ask one question per post, and you should explain what you did to try to find the answer before you posted.

Answer (score 2):

Each number is a pair of verb phrases divided by a "/". One of the two verb phrases is used correctly, one is used incorrectly. You circle the correct option of the two and then go to the next pair.

Comment: Sir. Could you give me correct answers for all?

Comment: @SiThu, maybe it would be a better learning experience if you posted what you thought the answers were and we could correct you.  You won't learn as much if we just give you the answers.

Answer (score 0):

This exercise focuses on the differences between different Present tenses. You have to choose the correct options that complete the text. I suggest that you give it a try and then ask here if you have any queries.